# How do I use checkboxes to convert currencies (moneys) from US to whatever the user has checked with Jquery/Inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="Author" content="Micah Cave">
<title>Ice 11</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
   
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#convert").click( function() {
        
        var dollarAmount = $('input:text').val();

        if ( $("#usa").is(':checked') ) 
            dollarAmount = dollarAmount*1;
                
        if ( $("#russia").is(':checked') ) 
            dollarAmount = dollarAmount * 73.18;
    });
});

</script>
   
</head>

<body>
    
<h1>Cave</h1>
<h2>Part 1B</h2>
    
<p>Type in the starting amount (in US dollars) here: <input type="text"></p>
<input type="checkbox" id="usa">US Dollars <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="russia">Russian Ruble <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="france">France Francs <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="japan">Japanese Yen <br>
<input type="button" id="convert" value="Convert currency(s)">

<p id="pasteHere"></p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

So I need to take the value that's entered in the input box above, and then if they check off any box(s) to then convert each checked boxs currency from US to whatever was selected, and then print out the results each time using if statements.

Comment: Why the first text box does not have "id" attribute?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I needed it since I'm grabbing the value from the text in the script above and there is only 1 text box

Comment: Do you want to print the result into the `<p id="pasteHere"></p>` ?

Comment: Yeah, so I have managed to only get 1 thing to print like "Russian Rubles", but I had US and Russian Rubles checked off

Comment: Also I forgot to re-add   $("#pasteHere").html(); but that only seems to print out just 1 thing to the id="pasteHere"

Comment: Do you mean when the user clicks on the 'convert' button, your script print all the selected currencies value to the `<p id="pasteHere"></p>`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I'm being a bit confusing, so the text box is in US Dollars, and then when a user checks off a box I'm supposed to convert that to the checked boxes currency and then to paste each box that was checked on to the page.

Comment: Pro tip: write a summarized title to make it easier to read. Perhaps something like "How do i detect the selected checkbox" or "How do i detect the selected checkbox to convert currency"

Comment: Got it, sorry this is my very first time using stackoverflow so I'll be sure to do that next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a function called convert,when convert button click or checkbox click then call that function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="Author" content="Micah Cave">
<title>Ice 11</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
   
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#convert").click(convert);
    $("input:checkbox").click(convert)
});

function convert(){
  var dollarAmount = $('input:text').val();

  var result = " "
  if ( $("#usa").is(':checked') ) 
      result += dollarAmount*1 + ";";

  if ( $("#russia").is(':checked') ) 
      result += dollarAmount * 73.18 + ";";
      
  $("#pasteHere").text(result)
}

</script>
   
</head>

<body>
    
<h1>Cave</h1>
<h2>Part 1B</h2>
    
<p>Type in the starting amount (in US dollars) here: <input type="text"></p>
<input type="checkbox" id="usa">US Dollars <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="russia">Russian Ruble <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="france">France Francs <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="japan">Japanese Yen <br>
<input type="button" id="convert" value="Convert currency(s)">

<p id="pasteHere"></p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've been stuck on this for a bit now and didn't even think about adding a function

Comment: I am very glad that help you,could you please mark the answer as correct

Comment: Yes, but uhhh how do I do that? Lol sorry completely new to using stackoverflow

Comment: there will be a right sign on the left of answer,click it should be ok

Answer (score 0):

That is my solution:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   let selectedCurrencies = [];
   $("#convert").click(function() {
     let dollarAmount = $('input:text').val();
     let checkBoxList = $('input:checked');
     let resultText = "";
     for (let i = 0; i < checkBoxList.length; i++) {
       resultText += "US "+dollarAmount+" dollar =";
       switch (checkBoxList[i].id) {
         case 'usa':
           resultText += dollarAmount * 1;
           break;
         case "russia":
           resultText += dollarAmount * 73.18;
           break;
       }
       resultText+=" "+(checkBoxList[i].nextSibling.textContent)+"<br>";
       
     }
      $("#pasteHere").html(resultText);
   });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Cave</h1>
<h2>Part 1B</h2>

<p>Type in the starting amount (in US dollars) here: <input type="text"></p>
<input type="checkbox" id="usa">US Dollars <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="russia">Russian Ruble <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="france">France Francs <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="japan">Japanese Yen <br>
<input type="button" id="convert" value="Convert currency(s)">

<p id="pasteHere"></p>
```

Comment: Ahhhhh I hadn't thought of using a switch statement either, thank you!